# Should I leave the job I just started to work for Amazon (Europe)

Tags: software-industry, salary, career-development, software-development

I am a software engineer in a western European country. I started working for a local medium-sized tech company here last week, but now I also got an offer from Amazon. Amazon is offering to pay much more. Almost 130k Euro/year, which is an insane amount of money in my opinion. The other company pays just over 80k Euro/year, which is not amazing, but still good. Both gross/before tax. Both are mostly cash with very little stock. Amazon's offer shifts to more stock vests after two years whereas the cash component actually declines. The other company stays this way, mostly cash. I have about 5 years experience, depending on how you count.

Now I am conflicted on what to do and am looking for some fresh perspectives. Here are a few thoughts:

- Money is not the biggest issue for me right now. I still have heaps of cash (100k roughly) lying around from previous jobs and I don't even spend a lot. Tbh even 80k will be more than I spend anyway. But more money is never a bad thing either. Especially when it's so much more.
- I really like the company I started at. Good people, no bullshit, project seems alright. I think Amazon would be great aswell, but I don't know that for sure. Where as with the other company I can see myself working there for a while for sure even after a few days. The project domain also interests me slightly more than at Amazon, but not much of a difference, it's almost a tie.
- In the past two years with Covid I had a lot of turbulance with job changes, failed starts, moves etc. I am really anxious about picking a job that won't work out and then I have to switch again. I am really looking for stability, belonging and purpose at the moment. I think I might get that at Amazon, but with the other company I feel confident even after a few days. The other company has also already started. I would have to quit two weeks after joining. I am in a job right now and everything is settled, which I really enjoy at the moment; Amazon said they would be quick but still a few weeks out. This is important to me, but at the same time it feels dumb to be driven by short term emotional needs that might be completely different again in a short time.
- I have heard Amazon has bad Work/Life-Balance. I am not lazy, but if I have the choice to do 1.5X the work for 1.5X the pay, right now, I would rather stick with 1X for both. Again, I don't know that Amazon will be like that, but my current job doesn't seem very stressful at all.
- Amazon could be amazing. I can learn a lot of things. I also appreciate the option to one day move around to other countries and/or projects within such a large company. it will also be a good name to have on the CV.

In summary, I think my gut feeling is telling me to stay in the company I am in right now. But am I being stupid turning down such an opportunity to work for Amazon? Would I be stupid turning down so much money? It feels like I am scared of experiments and risk, which is a bit unusual for me. Normally I am much more adventurous, but the past two Covid years have shaken me up quite a bit. I am worried that that is blinding me.

Disclaimer: I am not going to disclose the company I am working for to retain at least some form of anonymity, Amazon on the other hand is massive with loads of people getting offers in western Europe, I could be any of them. Also I want to hear people's opinion on Amazon.
Disclaimer 2: I know I have to make my own decision. And I will. I just want to hear some perspectives from peers.

Thanks

Comment: Oh... Yes, I was hoping for people's opinions. I didn't realise that was not allowed.

Comment: @Peter, This question is allowed. You can get people's opinions. Joe's point is that there is a process to close a question. For example, if 5 people with high reputations (scores) vote to close a question, then it will be closed (i.e. the question is not deleted but will not accept answers). But, there is also a process to reopen a closed question.  If 5 people with high reputations (scores) vote to reopen a closed question, then it will be reopened for everyone to answer. This site is operated on a voting basis or democratic principle.

Comment: "now I also got an offer from Amazon" - presumably this follows you making some kind of *application*, or did they just offer you a job out of nowhere? What were your thoughts when you applied?

Comment: @AakashM Good point. They reached out to me initially, but I applied myself and of course went through the whole process. I think if both offers would have come in at the same time, I would have taken Amazon. But now I know I enjoy the other one already. Is that stupid? Because I am gonna like Amazon, too?

Comment: Have you thought about that Amazon is famous for treating low-level workers horribly? Are you ethically fone working there?

Answer (score 6):

Amazon Europe is known to pay IT personnel quite well. But yes, it's known for a bad work/life-balance too. 80k vs 130k is a huge difference though.

I wouldn't stay at any company just for the sense of loyalty or obligation. (Mind you, I mean for-profit companies). Companies get rid of you when you're not useful anymore so why should you involve emotional factors in your decision?

You have to decide yourself how attractive the perspective is for you though. I just turned down a job last week that would pay 70% net more than what I have now, because of non-financial reasons. There's no one answer valid for everybody. Imagine your life in a year and in 5 years 1) if you decide to switch, 2) if you decide to stay. Which perspective is more attractive?

Answer (score 0):

Go to amazon. Period.

When recession/ firing comes no company cares about you. They only see if you fit the box or not. Amazon is a great place to work with. The exposure you get there is immense.

Comment: "When recession/ firing comes no company cares about you." That's not correct in Europe. Companies try to retain their talent even during recession and there is government support enabling them to do so.

Comment: @Roland, I've witnessed people being fired after 15 years of committed work because their new boss didn't like them. There's always an option to get rid of somebody, also in Europe.

Comment: @BigMadAndy Yes, of course. I'm talking specifically about being layed off during/due to recession.

Comment: If company decides to get rid of people, what ever be rules the people will be fired. Fundamentally the investor is paying; why will he be quiet?

Comment: @chen, How do you think the work-life-balance factor for software engineers is at Amazon (compared to average companies) ?

Comment: Terrible. They pay you double. Extract triple. Given that you are just 5y experience you will be able to withstand. Btw, many Europians are already working with amazon so dont be super afraid to join.

Comment: What I'm saying is that tech companies in Europe right now are very reluctant to decide "to get rid of people". And the governments make it easy for them to no have to lay off employees.

Comment: @chen Some people will be able to withstand. Other people would not. Some people really value their work-life-balance. Others will be more happy to get that Amazo experience. There is not one-size-fits-all-answer, which is why something like "Go to Amazon.Period" is not super-helpful.